# How do ∀x [P(x) ∨ Q(x)] and ∀x [P(x)] ∨ ∀x [Q(x)] differ in their meaning?

Tags: computer-science, mathematical-expressions

How do `∀x [P(x) ∨ Q(x)]` and `∀x [P(x)] ∨ ∀x [Q(x)]` differ in their meaning?

I thought it was because when `∀x` is defined twice there is a possibility of a different x value for both `P(x)` and `Q(x)` but then I noticed it was for all so this would not be the case as it would use every x value.

Could you have two different sets of x?

Comment: Yes, every `∀` creates its own identifier scope. The first `x` is a different variable than the second `x`. You can (should) rename one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose P(X) means "X is even" and Q(X) means "X is odd" and assume you're taking about integers. Is the first formula true? How about the second? Does that explain why they're not the same?

Answer (score 1):

The first means:

> For every thing condition P is true or condition Q is true (or both).

The second means:

> Condition P is true for all things or condition Q is true for all things.